# Rails using arrays with forms & validation inclusion of

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

Trying to get some good advice on the best approach to using arrays for form select but using the same array to test inclusion of for the validation.

Right now I have it but building the arrays within the elements and validation ie,

```
# Form
<%= f.select(:status, [['Live','live'], ['Paused', 'paused']]) %>

# Model
validates :status, :inclusion => { :in => %w(live paused) }
```

I'm sure there would be a better way to store these arrays and use them !

Thanks for any advise you can provide.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can add these two constants to your model and then call the validation:

```
VALID_STATES = ["live", "paused"]
SELECT_STATES = VALID_STATES.map { |s| [s.capitalize, s] }
validates :status, :inclusion => { :in => Model::VALID_STATES }
```

Comment: Agh nice, Once small tweak Model::VALID_STATES,  Thank you